# 1001 Beers You Must Try Before You Die

Tags: specialty-beers, recommendations

Does anybody know someone that has completed the 1001 beers of the book:
1001 Beers You Must Try Before You Die - Adrian Tierney-jones

If there is someone here trying, please tell me: In your opinion which beer was the best until now and why do you consider it the best.

Comment: "Best" is going to be relative to the tastes of each individual.  Is there anything you can do to make your question less subjective?

Comment: I know it's relative, and for me that is the interesting thing. 
I'm going to change a little and hope you may contribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not done the 1001 to drink before you die, but I have rated more than 1000 beers on RateBeer. :)

I have many favourites, but a favourite depends on so many things! Westvletern 8 is one of the best beers I have ever had, but I would not like to drink it while mowing the lawn! Snow and Bud are great for quenching a thirst, but not something I would drink with good meal.

London Pride, Stone Ruination, Lagunitas Hop Stoopid, Dogfish Head 60, 90, Midas Touch. Weihnstephaner Weiss, Pilsner Urquell, Duvel, Cockpit Crazy Diamond, Windhoek Light, Badger Golden Glory... The list just continues.

Use sites like Ratebeer and BeerAdvocate to see what others think of the beers.

And sometimes the best beer is the one in front of you. :D

Comment: Which are the best beers from Africa in your opinion? And which beer from South Africa would you recommend?

Comment: Well done @atron-seige, as soon as possible I will taste these.

Comment: @Leo, African beers tend to be pale lager. SAB also happens to own almost all of the African breweries, which again explains the pale lager trend. Some of the pale lagers are better than others, but I can't really think of a single beer that amazed me. The traditional beer (umqombothi [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umqombothi]) is an "interesting" beer. :p A few good breweries Devils Peak, CBC, Gilroys, Triggerfish, Cockpit, Chameleon. I will happily spend a day at any of these breweries drinking all of their beers!

Comment: @MarceloMachado, I highly recommend that you take your journey seriously and take lots of notes. Your palate will grow immensely over the next year if you pay attention to what you are experiencing. Notes help you learn and it shows you how far you've grown (from stone fruit, to cherry, to black cherry). It also helps you to make sure that you don't accidentally buy a bad beer twice. Join us on ratebeer.

Comment: Good idea @AtronSeige, from now on I will take lots of notes in order no learn. Beer really pleases me but I'm still a newbe. However a journey of a 1000(1001) miles begins with a single step.

Answer (score 1):

I really like Super Bock from Portugal, it reminds me a little
of Heineken but with a less bitter taste. Resembles my memories
of the times that I lived there. From the beers I've tasted in
Europe (Stella Artois, Birra Moretti, Amstel, San Miguel, Estrella etc) I would say it's the best between the lagers.
It's a pale lager from the Unicer brewery with 5,2% of alcohol.

And there is a brazilian brand I like a lot thats called Áustria from
Krug Bier Brewery: http://www.krug.com.br/
My favourite is the Hefe Weizen for sure.